# How to mock this EmailCreation for unit Test in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, .net-core

Hi I´m trying to test a class of my project that generate a SendResponse with an Email template

this is my code

```
            await Email.Create()
                .To(request.Parcel.CustomerEmail)
                .Subject(emailSubject)
                .UsingTemplateFromEmbedded(emailTemplate, new ParcelReceivedEmailModel()
                {
                    Parcel =  request.Parcel,
                    Shop = shopInfo
                }, GetType().Assembly)
                .SendAsync(cancellationToken);
```

in the xunit test class i´m mocking IFluentEmailFactory to test that, this is my mock code:

```
            _mockFluentEmailFactory.Setup(x => x.Create()
            .To(It.IsAny<string>())
            .Subject(It.IsAny<string>())
            .UsingTemplateFromEmbedded(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(),
              It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<string>())
            .SendAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(fakeSendResponse);
```

but i get allways a nullException and I don´t know why, can someone help me? im new doing test and it seems no to be so difficult

I search information in xunit

Comment: See SMTP transport example at following.  It may give you a clue : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
.UsingTemplateFromEmbedded(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<ParcelReceivedEmailModel>(), It.IsAny<Assembly>(), It.IsAny<bool>())
```

Comment: Please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).